# Problema al iniciar sesion phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un gran problema, mi app/web ha dejado de funcionar. He probado a restaurar a una version en la que si funcionaba y sigue igual. He intentado entrar en mi panel phpMyAdmin a ver si estaba ahí el problema y me salta este error.
[image: Error en phpMyAdmin]

Como puedo solucionar este problema? no encuentro la solucion

Comment: Te está diciendo que no queda espacio en disco. Las sesiones de PHP por defecto crean un archivo, por ejemplo en `/var/lib/php5`. Si estás en un hosting compartido, significa que excediste tu cuota de almacenamiento. Cuando no hay espacio en disco tampoco se pueden ejecutar programas, porque éstos crean un archivo que identifica el proceso. Tienes que liberar espacio en disco de alguna manera.

Comment: No puede modificar archivos, ya que no los puede ejecutar, esto ocurre por qué te quedaste sin espacio de disco duro de tu hosting.

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que las sesión no se guarde, o se borre, porque mi base de datos no tendra más de 20 registros....

Comment: Las sesiones debieran expirar solas después de algunas horas. Pero sería más sano si borraras alguna otra cosa que tengas alojada ahí. ¿Tienes acceso ssh a la máquina o sólo a un panel tipo cPanel?

Comment: pues creo que solo tengo acceso a cPanel

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, he entrado desde el cPanel y he borrado algunos archivos, de todas formas el espacio en mi servidor es de 200mb.... tendré que ampliar, muchas gracias